# Hibernate get object and save as foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How to correctly save new record many to one?

1. Get object pcKey(one,works fine)
2. Create new computer object with foreign key (object pcKey)
3. Send to Dao class
4. Try to save object
5. Error

RegisterComputerService

```
public Boolean registerPc(String cpu, String gpu, String motherBoard,
        String hdd, String pcName, String pcKeyString) {

    IsPcKeyExistDao IsPcKeyExistDao = new IsPcKeyExistDao();
    PcKey pcKey = IsPcKeyExistDao.isKeyExist(pcKeyString);

    IsPcWithPcKeyActiveDao isPcWithPcKeyActiveDao = new IsPcWithPcKeyActiveDao();
    Boolean isPcExist = isPcWithPcKeyActiveDao.isPcExist(pcKey);


        RegisterPcDao registerPcDao = new RegisterPcDao();
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        computer.setPcKey(pcKey);
        computer.setRegDate(new Date());
        Boolean result = registerPcDao.registerPc(computer, pcKey);
        return result;
}
```

registerPc

```
    public Boolean registerPc(Computer computer, PcKey pcKey){

    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        tx.setTimeout(5);

        session.save(computer);
        tx.commit();

        return true;

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (RuntimeException rbe) {
            // log.error("Couldn’t roll back transaction", rbe);
            return false;
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
at com.want.ecdlejb.dao.RegisterPcDao.registerPc(RegisterPcDao.java:22)
at com.want.ecdlejb.services.RegisterComputerService.registerPc(RegisterComputerService.java:40)
at com.want.ecdlwar.computers.RegisterComputer.register(RegisterComputer.java:15)
at com.want.ecdlwar.rest.Rest.registryPc(Rest.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecdl`.`computers`, CONSTRAINT `computers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pc_key`) REFERENCES `pc_keys` (`pc_key`))
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1455)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1440)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
```

Mapping

PcKeys

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pcKey")
private Set<Computer> computerses;
```

Computers

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pc_key", nullable=false)
private PcKey pcKey;
```

isPcKeyExist

```
public PcKey isKeyExist(String pcKeyString) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        tx.setTimeout(5);

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PcKey.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("pcKey", pcKeyString));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("pcKeyStatus",
                ConstantsEjb.ACTIVE_STATUS));
        PcKey pcKey = (PcKey) criteria.uniqueResult();

        tx.commit();
        return pcKey;

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (RuntimeException rbe) {
            // log.error("Couldn’t roll back transaction", rbe);
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Post edited, mapping added

Comment: Now show `IsPcKeyExistDao.isKeyExist`

Comment: It works fine too, I checked.
Added

Comment: Why do you use eqOrIsNull?? I know that eqOrIsNull compares if one property is equals to an object (pcKeySctring), if pcKeyString is null, then it compares if the property is null, but if you want to get an unique object, I don't understand what is the goal for your case, you might have multiples null values in the columns pcKey and pcKeyStatus so you will get multiple results from that query.